# jQuery AJAX - Return dynamic content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I am making a jQuery Ajax form submit to a PHP page that I want to return values dynamically instead of all at once. For example, if my jQuery code is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "$PathToActions/Accounts.php",
      dataType: "html",
      data: "action=register&accounts=" + accounts,
      success: function(response){
           alert(response);
      });
```

My Accounts.php looks something like:

```
     <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        echo $i;
        sleep(2);
     } ?>
```

My code outputs 012345679 right now in a single JavaScript alert after a ~10 second delay. Is it possible to get it to output the values as soon as they are generated instead of all at once?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't do that ... the output only sent after php finish running

Comment: @Bang Dao - well, how would something like a shoutbox/chat room made in Ajax work? I believe it would be the same approach..

Comment: they use other way. I will pass as an answer

Comment: There is no such approach. Ajax chat just makes separate ajax requests every N seconds retreiving new data from server.

Comment: @Bang and @ehpc. Hmm I see. What approach do they use? Are they querying a database or so every few seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
key = something_identify_here; //I use global variable for easier to understand

setInterval(function()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "$PathToActions/Accounts.php",
      dataType: "html",
      data: "action=register&accounts=" + accounts + '&key=' + key,
      success: function(response){
           alert(response);
           //change the key if its need
      });
}, 2000); //do query foreach 2 second
```

And on the php file, we code something like this

```
showContentByKey($_GET['key']);
```

The main idea here is: you do a ajax query for each 2 second and display the returned data.
On your server, the php script send some data (maybe difference from each time) when requested.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can do it through `ob_start`.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        echo $i;
        sleep(2);
        ob_flush();
        flush();
     } 

ob_end_clean(); 
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't serve the purpose. Yes, it works if I visit the PHP page directly but it still returns the value to the AJAX form with 10 second delay and returns its all at once.

Comment: @Aamir sorry flushing output outside the loop. now the code is corrected.